# What "two" is Waymond referring to?

Tags: everything-everywhere-all-at-once

Inside the van , Alpha Gong Gong speaks on the screen
to Alpha Waymond, who is sitting in a chair wearing tech-enhanced gear to
control his body in other universes:

> ALPHA GONG GONG: Do not engage! Run! Run!

The scene shifts to a room where Alpha Gong Gong is sitting in Smart-Chair and
can speak English fluently. Alpha Waymond and Evelyn are with him:

> Alpha Waymond: Watch these **two** here while I deal with Jobu.
>
> ALPHA GONG GONG: I'm not risking the safety of the Alpha verse for this.

What "two" is Waymond referring to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He can only be referring to the "native" Gong Gong whom Alpha Gong Gong is controlling at the time, despite not being mentally present he's naturally going to need his body alive when he gets back.